# Difference between publishOn and parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, reactive-programming, project-reactor

What is the difference between `publishOn` and `parallel`? As far as I understand `publishOn` influences the further processing of the operators chain by executing it using couple of threads. But `parallel` seems to work exactly the same as it. By default it creates a thread pool of size == #cores and processes the operator's chain the same. Or am I missing some subtlety?

The [Schedulers](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers) section states:

> [publishOn] takes signals from upstream and replays them downstream while executing the callback on a worker from the associated Scheduler

and,

> a fixed pool of workers that is tuned for parallel work (Schedulers.parallel()). It creates as many workers as you have CPU cores.

Therefore `publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()` creates as many threads are cores and executes the subsequent `operators` in the chain with these workers.

But then the [Parralel](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux) section states:

> you can use the parallel() operator on any Flux. By itself, this method does not parallelize the work. Rather, it divides the workload into "rails" (by default, as many rails as there are CPU cores).
>
> In order to tell the resulting ParallelFlux where to execute each rail
>   (and, by extension, to execute rails in parallel) you have to use
>   runOn(Scheduler). Note that there is a recommended dedicated Scheduler
>   for parallel work: Schedulers.parallel().

Two examples below:

```
Flux.range(1, 10)
    .parallel(2)
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -> " + i));
```

and

```
Flux.range(1, 10)
    .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -> " + i));
```

Are the above two examples equivalent assuming the computer has two cores?

Answer (score 3):

I *think* I have the answer to this.

After some testing I found out that `publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()` will process your `Flux` on separate threads but in sequence.

But,

using `parallel().runOn(Schedulers.parallel())` will split your `Flux` into amount of cores you have, and each of these new `Fluxes` will be processed in parallel. Therefore the data in each of the new `Fluxes` will probably be processed in sequence but the `Fluxes` together will be processes in parallel.